# Congratulations! Japanese Language is graduating!

Tags: discussion

It's a big day. You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Japanese Language met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and after a review, the Community Team determined that you're good to go. Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

What does this mean exactly? Graduation works in two phases. Starting today, you'll receive the following benefits

- You will soon have an election for community-voted moderators
- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- You will be able to select [your own community ads](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1421/1628)

In the coming months, the site will receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, and although you're looking at wait of several months, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. There are also bound to be bugs as the new process gets rolled out so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeay! ついに卒業！JLSEの皆さん、お疲れ様でした！

Comment: Oh, hey, the "beta" label is gone already!  I guess that comes first :-)

Comment: お疲れ様です！Keep up the good work.

Comment: I haven't been active here for a while, but delighted to see that we're graduating. Great work everyone! :D

Comment: What's the official place for heated arguments about the site design? ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's been six weeks since the announcement.

**What's happened so far?**

- > You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name

  Done!  This happened right away—at least, within a couple days of the announcement.
- > You will be able to select your own community ads

  We got [our community ads thread](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1421/community-promotion-ads-2015) right away, but some users have wondered whether or not they're actually showing up; see our [Are the community ads working?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1432/are-the-community-ads-working) thread on meta.

**What hasn't happened yet?**

- > You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network

  No word on this yet, but that's okay.  We don't migrate very often to begin with, so I'm not sure we really need migration paths.  (Of course, we haven't had a community discussion about that yet!)
- > You will soon have an election for community-voted moderators

  No word of an election yet.

One more thing I noticed, although it wasn't mentioned in this post specifically: [the site switched to "Launched" status on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language) five days ago.

---

Now let's see how another Stack Exchange site, English Language Learners, is going:

1. ELL got its [graduation meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2634/230) on the same day as us.
2. ELL [lost its "beta" label](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2634/congratulations-english-language-learners-is-graduating/2647#2647) on the same day as us.
3. ELL got their [community ads thread](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/community-promotion-ads-2015) on the same day as us.
4. ELL [switched to "Launched" status on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) on the same day, too.

So I can't help but notice that the process has been very similar, but with one big difference: ELL has already had their moderation election!  Six weeks after the announcement, there are still no elections in sight here on Japanese.SE.

#### Is this an oversight, or are our elections just further down the pipeline?

Comment: Elections are currently down the pipeline - we had a snafu when we launched this process wherein we missed a bunch of things that happen along with graduation that we had overlooked - such as comment flag changes and pro tem moderator badge awarding. These were addressed last week, so we're now in the process of scheduling elections for the 8 remaining sites that need them, including Japanese. Sorry about the delay!