# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As your site is undergoing our new design-independent graduation process, you'll be enjoying your own run of design-independent Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- relevant linguistic blogs and websites
- events, conferences, or meetups for Japanese language scholarship
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 40 KB
- If the background of the image is white, there must be a 1x1 border of not-white at the edges of the ad

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1421).

Comment: As reference for ideas, EL&U's community ads: [2015](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5491/community-promotion-ads-2015), [2014](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/community-promotion-ads-2014),  [2013](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/community-promotion-ads-2013), [2012](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2223/community-promotion-ads-2012)

Comment: I'd like to make an ad like [this one from ELU](http://i.stack.imgur.com/27cPL.png), but linking to [our resources page](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/761#761).  But I'm no good at graphic design stuff.  I wonder if anyone in our community could make one :-)

Comment: One which just links to our resources page in general would be great. It's so impossible to find for new users.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Any ideas on what the resources page ad should look like?

Comment: "[ . . . ] this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form" ← I just noticed this.  It doesn't pre-fill the answer field with anything for me!

Answer (score 11):

[image: Community-Compiled Japanese Learning Resources: explore our dictionaries, online courses, JLPT prep material, corpora, and more!]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Area 51 proposal for Korean Language and Usage Q&A site]

Answer (score 6):

[image: AnkiDroid: Memorize everything!]

Comment: Shamelessly advertising my app...

Comment: Woah, hold on, you're an AnkiDroid dev? Thank you so much for your work! I use AnkiDroid on a daily basis (mostly, it so happens, for Japanese vocabulary). I don't even know how I managed to memorize things before I found Anki...

Comment: @senshin: Yeah, you can blame me for the unimaginative app name ;-) I have maintained AnkiDroid alone for a long time, but thanks to it being open source, now some great volunteers have stepped in! Anyone reading this is welcome to join the team too :-) There are tons of new features to implement: https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/issues

Answer (score -2):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Comment: I think this sort of begs the question... does following the Twitter account actually help the community grow? As far as I can tell, all StackExchange twitter accounts have under 1k followers, and practically all of the tweets have no retweets or favorites. I think for JLSE, the majority of traffic comes from search engines, and in second place, other StackExchanges (we're lucky to have ja.stackoverflow -- how do we get an ad running there?! :-), so investing in Twitter seems like a weird choice.

Comment: We could join the friendly Twitter ad competition of a [range](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19015/33855) of [other](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3312/114855) SE [sites](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6840/community-promotion-ads-2015/6841#6841).

Comment: @DariusJahandarie ja.SO recently got a [community-ads] post (http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1994/), which doesn't seem to have the en.SO restriction that only open-source software projects may be advertised. Somebody from here who has an eye for graphics should definitely put an ad over there.