# Are the Community Ads working?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, advertising

Currently, we have two "live" ads, shown here: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1421

I haven't actually seen them on the main page, but apparently the counter increases, when clicking the ad on the above page, too.

> [image: clicks per day]

I clicked the Korean Language proposal ad 6 times & the resources ad once (on that page, not in the Community Ads meta post). Now the "clicks per day" have to increased to 6 & 1 clicks total, but these stats are not from them being shown as ads!

I have refreshed myself through about 50-60 different ads (questions and Area 51 proposals). The Korean proposal pops up every now and then, but that seems to be the up-to-date ad, coming directly from adzerk.net, *not* from our Community Ads. (The way to tell the difference is with the link, but also visually: the adzerk ad has "42% committed", whereas the community ad shows "39% committed".) ([Related question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267157/how-often-are-the-proposal-png-files-on-area-51-updated).)

So I'm left wondering **are the Community Ads actually working**?

Comment: If it becomes clear that the ads aren't working then it might make sense to tag this question with [meta-tag:bug], which I believe alerts SO staff to the question.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie I think [support] also alerts SO staff, but I was waiting first to see if anyone came by saying "I've seen one of your ads". Since nobody has come forth (and I've polled around in chat), I think this might well be a bug, so I've gone ahead and added the [bug] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed, as promised [here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/community-promotion-ads-2016#comment3658_1507) (comment from Feb. 26, 2016.)

Comment: Confirmed!  I finally saw an ad :-)