# Privilege requirements have changed

Tags: discussion

I notice that the reputation required to access privileges has changed. Is this part of the new site design? This happened once before but it was a mistake and got fixed.

Given the number of users on the site some of these new reputation requirements seem prohibitively high.

Comment: @Earthliŋ It seems that the requirement change came with the design update, not graduation.

Comment: I think many of the users who remain with the higher privileges on this site are no longer active. Other active higher-rep users prefer to ask/answer questions over administrative tasks - there's nothing wrong with this, but it's worth noting, as it can appear there are more administratively active users than there actually are.  Some of the users previously doing various administrative tasks have lost many of their privileges, which could lead to lower quality content/administrative participation on this site.

Comment: @Earthliŋ The site design is considered the last part of graduation, and in the new graduation process, privilege levels are coupled with the site design. That's intended.

Comment: Related meta post on ELL: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2957/is-access-review-queues-privilege-eligibility-revised

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the increase in reputation for attaining privileges is coupled to the full design, as was mentioned in our graduation announcement [Congratulations! Japanese Language is graduating!](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/congratulations-japanese-language-is-graduating)

> In the coming months, the site will receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege.

The levels can be seen [here in the help center](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), the highest level being at 25,000.

I'm counting about 10 active users with over 10,000 reputation, who will have "access to moderator tools".

Comment: By my count, there's about 4-6 active users (if not including diamond mods, and users who AFAIK don't use/mostly don't use mod tools) with 10k+.

Comment: Do we need a lot of users with the moderator tools privilege? I had them in beta and they were useful for practically nothing.

Comment: @Blavius Not so much, but the inline tag editing was nice. 2000 rep to edit questions/answers seems a bit on the steep side though.

Comment: @user3856370 The 2000 rep limit for edits is for edits that are applied immediately. You can still suggest edits, I think. (Reviewing edits is much easier than making the edit, so "suggesting" an edit is actually *very* helpful.)