# Some posts not showing up in question list on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed

Two of our most recent posts, [How to "Signal" Willingness to Help With Language Barrier Issues](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/how-to-signal-willingness-to-help-with-language-barrier-issues) and [Privilege requirements have changed](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/privilege-requirements-have-changed), don't show up on the question list on meta.

1. They don't show up on the [front page on the active questions tab](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=active):

   [image: screen shot of front page]
2. They don't show up on [the latest questions list](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) either:

   [image: screen shot of questions list]

Why don't these posts show up?  The only links to these questions I can see are in the "hot meta posts" section.

Comment: It seems chocolate, I, (and likely other users) are also experiencing this.  StackOverflow probably utilizes an "eventually consistent" distributed database, which means that sometimes it takes time for the computers to "agree" on the newest data.  If we're being served by a computer that hasn't "caught up" yet, it might be the cause.  Still, 20+ hours seems like a long time....

Comment: And now it seems to be working for me.

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy no, we don't use eventual consistency here; see my answer for more context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, because I'm an idiot. I've recently deployed a major change (rewrite) to our "tag engine" that drives most of the question lists. I had an "off by one" bug that meant that whenever we reloaded the service (which would normally  be very rare, but I've redeployed it many times over the last few days), it lost count and missed one post (the most recent post). And if we restart, it would of course save everything it knew, and reload losing the *now* most recent, etc.

The "a very small number of posts are missing" problem was pointed out earlier today, and I reverted to "v1" while I investigated, which is why WeirdlyCheezy couldn't see it. I have now fixed the underlying problem, re-deployed, reset the data, and re-enabled "v2". So: you should be fine now!

If there are any other glitches, please do shout.